# How to turn off a GPIO port on BeagleBone Black Wireless

Tags: linux, gpio, beagleboneblack, ttl

My task is to create a program to open and close an electronic valve that is plugged into GPIO ports on my BeagleBone, by using TTL signals.

Questions:

Can I do this?

How do I make an executable file to do this?

Can someone refer me to documentation on this?

Am I going about this in the wrong way?

Thank you.

P.S. If you couldn't already tell I am very new to this.

Comment: C++ would not have any high-level constructs to manipulate GPIO ports. Your kernel, however, will - look at https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gpio/sysfs.txt

Comment: Thank you, I edited the post since now I have more knowledge of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes
- There are *many* ways. It's actually a pretty standard Linux computer and you can use any of a "million" different programming languages to achieve this. This also means you don't have to look for "Beaglebone" specific instructions (beyond the GPIO info below), but your problem is just "How do I write a program that can write text to a file on Linux?". Bonus: This sounds easy and *it **is** easy!*
- Yes, take a look here for the hardware specific part:
  https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/157
  It describes fairly well both the new and the old sysfs interfaces you can use to manipulate GPIOs.

  - Depending on the language of your choice, there may already be bindings or a library to abstract this.
- No (only based on the information you provided, are there other requirements?)
- We all were new at this at some point, don't worry.

Sidenote: It's generally a good idea to make sure that you are running the latest firmware. In case of the BB-Family you can find them here: http://beagleboard.org/latest-images

Comment: Thanks, great answer.